# How to use jquery autocomplete with server/sql data fetched with php?

Tags: php, jquery

Is there something wrong with this code?

Form input:

```
<input type="text" id="currentTag" name="currentTag" class="inputbox"/>
```

jquery:

```
$("#currentTag").autocomplete({
    source:'getautocomplete.php',
    minLength:1
});
```

getautocomplete.php

```
$term=$_GET["term"];
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE tag_value LIKE '%".$term."%' ORDER BY tag_value ");
$results=array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $results[] = array('label' => $row['tag_value']);
}
echo json_encode($results);
```

getautocomplete.php output when script is called directly:

```
[{"label":"birdseye"},{"label":"doggy"},{"label":"tomhat"}]
```

'SOLVED'
It's a bit of a hack job, but I ended up setting source as a jquery var instead of url. Then used php include to echo the json into the var. All this in a Joomla site. Some conflict that I don't understand was happening, because the above code worked in a test file outside of Joomla. If anyone knows the conflict I'd curious to learn. Cheers.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#currentTag" ).autocomplete({
        source: tags
    });
});
var tags = <?php include("getautocomplete.php");?>;
```

Comment: This might seem like a trivial question, but you do connect to your database first right?

Comment: What's the error/unexpected behaviour? Nothing happens? Exception? JS error?

Comment: i hope this is just an example because you will be hacked in seconds with SQL Injection

Comment: What you have to do is to make an `ajax` function to get the `$results` and set it in the `source` of the `autocomplete`.

Comment: Not relevant to whatever problem you are facing, but the fact that you are still using `mysql_*` instead of *MySQLi* or *PDO* is in itself wrong. Do you see any errors in your console. Is your autocomplete input not getting updated?

Comment: @Phillip yes, it's connecting fine, outputs json data

Comment: @artm nothing happens, copy and pasted an example from tutorial though and autocomplete works fine when data is defined in jquery variable.

Comment: you could try and log the XMLHttpRequest to see if the source can actually be loaded

Comment: give sample code how you are passing values in js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this link http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

1. Include all js .
2. Get the data from MySQL using Ajax.   Proceed With
3. what you did now.

In the above link you will find demo source code see once

try this once

```
 $( "#currentTag" ).autocomplete({
source: function( request, response ) {
  $.ajax({
  url: "getautocomplete.php",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  data: {
 q: request.term
   },
   success: function( data ) {
  response( data );
   }
 });
 },
minLength: 3
  });
```

Comment: dont provide links to examples, provide the examples themselves (you know in case the site goes down or something)

Comment: besides, fromt he jquery api : String: When a string is used, the Autocomplete plugin expects that string to point to a URL resource that will return JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

There is a few thing wrong here, it could be any of the problems

- i assume you connect to the db first, this is not shown in the example but that might be the problem
- you should make sure you escape your `$term`, because you give the availability of SQL injection
- you should avoid useing `SELECT *` if you only need `tag_value`
- you should use mysql_fetch_assoc if you want to use assoc arrays in your result
- you should make sure the source URL is correct, it is a relative path the way you've put it, try to always use absolute paths, you never know where your script will be used (and with pretty urls, this becomes worse)